# Get webcam stream resolution without adding video to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a video-object with a webcam stream to apply to a canvas. Can I get the webcam streams resolution without drawing it in the DOM?

```
// Triangel side length
const video = document.createElement('video')
const v = document.getElementById('video')
const vc = v.getContext('2d')
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then((stream) => {
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
  console.log(video)
  video.play()
  //this is where I want the stream resolution.
  vc.drawImage(video, -250, -250)

  loop()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [videoWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130960(v=vs.85).aspx) and [videoHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130959(v=vs.85).aspx) property of a video element to get its resolulation *(width x height)*, even without adding the element to the DOM. These properties return an intrinsic width / height of a video in CSS pixels.

```
const video = document.createElement('video')
const v = document.getElementById('video')
const vc = v.getContext('2d')
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
}).then((stream) => {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    console.log(video)
    video.play()
    // get video / stream resolution
    video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        console.log('resolution: ' + this.videoWidth + ' x ' + this.videoHeight);
    };
    vc.drawImage(video, -250, -250)
    loop()
})
```

***note :*** you must call for these properties after the `loadedmetadata` event is fired.